# N2 CMS - where are the codebehind files?

Tags: asp.net, projects-and-solutions, code-behind, n2

I'm using the N2 CMS system for ASP.NET. Well I say 'using', I'm really just trying to develop a tiny understanding of it.

One of the things that's obstructing me is that it's set up in a way I've not seen before. Where are the codebehind files for the pages?

Can anyone tell me for example, where is the code for /Edit/default.aspx? How on earth do I debug what it is doing?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always used to be in N2.Edit.dll, but by the look of it they've rearranged this in more recent builds - I'm not 100% if it's now in N2.Management.dll or in N2.dll itself.

As usual the easist thing to do is to get hold of the source code (or an SVN checkout of the correct version), build it yourself and then replace the DLLs you were using with your built versions and their PDBs - you can then step into these correctly. You might want to go back to the regular releases for deployment, though.

If it's still Edit/default.aspx for you then I guess you're on the 1.5 code or thereabouts? In that case N2.Edit is built from src/wwwroot in the source code. You can just drop the entire src/wwwroot/Edit directory into place in your app and run it from the codebehind files there, not a compiled N2.Edit - that's easier to tweak, although I think it was easier to step through using a built DLL.

You may have to hunt around the build tree for all of the DLLs - I don't think they all get copied into one place. I used to take the DLLs from the N2.Edit.Tests project bin directory, and N2.Extensions and N2.Security from the N2.Extensions.Tests bin directory.

Comment: That is horribly, insanely complicated. I thought N2 was supposed to be simple to get up and running with.

Comment: Like any of these things it's not too bad once you've got it working the first time :-/ I guess they weren't expecting you to want to debug the edit code.